# CQWP filter greater than a number on a calculated field does not work

Tags: 2010, filter, content-query-web-part

I have a calculated column that produces values from 0 to 20. While filtering the query for items greater or equal to 16 I still get all the values. The result of the Calculated column is a number (and not a text).

The query does successfully the filtering on another parameter (open, close).

The 2 parameters are correlated by AND (must be open and must be above 16).

Why it is not working?

Comment: Try exporting the CQWP and have a look the CAML query. If needed try tweaking the query and re import the webpart to the page

Comment: How do I look at the CAML query?

Comment: You can find your query filters in the exported xml with property names like: FilterField1. There is a QueryOverride property where you specify your own CAML. Some guidance here: http://blog.riccardocelesti.it/extend-content-query-web-part-with-queryoverride/. Also have you tried setting filter to greater than 15 rather than greater than or equal to 16

Comment: I have found the property (<property name="FilterField2" type="string">Severity</property>), how should I modify it? I have also tried with greater than but it behaves the same

Comment: Have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested this and it works for me:
Replace the `QueryOverride` property in the exported webpart as below (updated column names according to your list columns) and re import the webpart.

**Rating** is a **calculated column** in the query below with an output of type **number**. **Status** is a **Choice** field (dropdown)

```
 <property name="QueryOverride" type="string" >
              <![CDATA[
            <Where>
           <And>
            <Gt>
               <FieldRef Name='Rating' />
               <Value Type='Number'>1</Value>
            </Gt>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='Status' />
               <Value Type='Choice'>Close</Value>
            </Eq>
         </And>
         </Where>]]>
            </property>
```

Comment: Instead of rating I need to put my field name, right? and the status field does work from the query interface, am I forced to put it in the code or I can only put in the code the severity field? The number '1' is my number 16? or do I have to leave 1?

Comment: You need to add both fields to the query. Replace 'Rating' field with your calculated field name and replace "Status" field with your choice field name. Replace number 1 with 15

Comment: Did this not work for you?

Comment: for now I did a workflow that was replicating the total, I am going to try your other method tomorrow. I would still like to know why the query fails to recognize the value as number, I have seen in some forums people doing it fine with SP 2013

Comment: I think the query fails because the CQWP seems to configure the calculated field value as string and the only way to correct that is by overriding the default query by specifying your own CAML which works as expected.

Comment: I have tried your code above replacing the line with 'queryoverride' with your piece and it shows absolutely nothing. My only changes is rating (in my case is severity), 15 instead of 1 and Open instead of close.

Comment: If there were no errors that means that query didnt find any match. What field type is your status column? Query requires internal field names and also what is the field type and internal name of your status field? Let me know your internal field names and field types- I will update the CAML in my answer accordingly

Comment: the status is originally the category field. Now it works. So for the number 15 the query you wrote does only 'numbers greater than 15' and not 'greater or equal'?

Comment: To use number 16 in your query instead of 15 you can replace the <Gt> tag with <Geq>. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms416296.aspx

Comment: is it normal that when you edit the contentquery.webpart and re-import it, you are not able any longer to edit anything from the user interface?

Comment: Yes, because you are overriding the default query. You can extend the query to cover for more logic or conditions :)